# Ember: Consume Service in Component

Tags: ember.js

I simply want to display my longitude on my app landing page/index/application.hbs.  I am embarrassed to say how long I have been working at this!  Can anyone help me?

```
//geoservice.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    longitude: function(position){
        return position.coords.longitude;
    },
    latitude: function(position){
        return position.coords.latitude;
    }
});

//geo-component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    geoservice: Ember.inject.service(),
    myLongitude: function(){
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                return this.get('geoservice').longitude(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition());
            } else {
                return "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }.on('init'),
});

//application.hbs
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember</h2>

{{outlet}}
{{geo-component.myLongitude}}
```

Comment: The geolocation API is published through the [navigator.geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem wasn't consuming a service in a component, but that 1) the `Geolocation` API is asynchronous, and 2) you don't render a component like you did. This works:

*app/components/geo-location.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  geo: Ember.inject.service(),
  loading: true,
  error: null,
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,

  setPosition: Ember.on('init', function() {
    this.get('geo').getPosition().then((position) => {
      this.set('latitude', position.latitude);
      this.set('longitude', position.longitude);
      this.set('loading', false);
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.set('error', error);
    });
  })
});
```

*app/services/geo.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  getPosition() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((success, error) => {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error)
      } else {
        error( new Error("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.") );
      }
    }).then((position) => {
      return { latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude };
    });
  }
});
```

*app/templates/components/geo-location.hbs*

```
{{#if error}}
  {{error}}
{{else if loading}}
  Loading...
{{else}}
  lat: {{latitude}}, long: {{longitude}}
{{/if}}
```

*app/templates/application.hbs*

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember</h2>

{{geo-location}}
```

Comment: Wow thanks!  That's a huge help.  Could you tell me about the =>?  Is that a legit javascript operator?

Comment: `() => {}` is an ES6 feature shorthand for `function (){}`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. ember-cli uses [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert ES6 into ES5 so it works in today's browsers. :)

Comment: @RonRoyston That syntax has the additional advantage of binding `this` in the function body to the `this` of the enclosing scope, rather than Javascript's iffy default of `window`. (In this case, `this` would refer to your geo-location component instance.)